# Test whole range of possible inputs for a given question

Tags: python

Is there a quick way to find the maximum value (float) from a function and the corresponding arguments x, y that are both integers between 0 and 100 (inclusive)? Do I need to use the assert function or something like that to get the range of all possible inputs?

```
def fun_A(x,y):
    import math
    if x == y:
       return 0
    first = math.cos((y%75)*(math.pi/180))
    second = math.sin((x%30)*(math.pi/180))
    return (first + second) / (abs(x - y))
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the max of fun_A  for 0<=x<=100, and 0<=y<=100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small problems like this it is probably fast enough to evaluate every possible combination and choose the maximum. The numpy library makes this easy to write and pretty fast as well:

```
import numpy as np

def fun_A(x, y):
    first = np.cos((y%75)*(np.pi/180))
    second = np.sin((x%30)*(np.pi/180))
    return np.where(x == y, 0, (first + second) / (abs(x - y)))

x, y = np.mgrid[0:101, 0:101]

f = fun_A(x, y)
maxindex = np.argmax(f)
print('Max =', f.flat[maxindex], ' at x =', x.flat[maxindex], 'y =',  y.flat[maxindex])
```

Output:

```
Max = 1.4591796850315724  at x = 89 y = 88
```

Things to note:

- I've just replaced calls to `math` with calls to `np`.
- x and y are matrices which allow us to evaluate every possible combination the two values in one function call.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this for the tan function :

```
from math import tan
y = 0
x = 0
for x_iteration in range(0, 101):
    if tan(x_iteration) > y :
        x = x_iteration
        y = tan(x_iteration) 

x = int(x) 
y = int(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straightforward to write a program to solve this:

```py
max_result = None
max_x = 0
max_y = 0
for x in range(0, 101):
    for y in range(0, 101):
       result = fun_A(x, y)

       if max_result is None or result > max_result:
           max_result = result
           max_x = x
           max_y = y

print(f"x={max_x} and y={max_y} produced the maximum result of {max_result}")
```

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question? @Downvoters, what's wrong here?